# How can I fix overflowing tables?

Tags: tables

I'm writing in markdown, and converting to PDF (via latex) using pandoc. It handles the conversion excellently, with the exception of tables, which overflow to the right of the page.

[image]

Is there an easy way of fixing this, whether in the mardown or in latex?

Comment: Lots of ways, you could use a smaller font or you could change `\begin{tabular}{lll}` to `\noindnet\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLL}` (`tabulary` package) or change individual columns from `l` to `p{some witdh}` for a hand-chosen width in each case, or....

Comment: As David says, there are lots of ways: we need to know what sort of output you actually want.